# Openstreetmap - part of a way

Tags: xml, openstreetmap

i want to create a way in OSM. It´s one street, but parts of it are limited to maxspeed=30.

How is this done in XML?

For example, part of the road with maxpeed 50:

```
<way id='12345' timestamp='2013-12-29T20:02:00Z' changeset='123'>
<nd ref='1' />
<nd ref='2' />
<nd ref='3' />
<nd ref='4' />
<tag k='maxspeed' v='50' />
<tag k='name' v='fooo' />
</way>
```

And now the part with 30:

```
<way id='56789' timestamp='2013-12-29T20:02:00Z' changeset='123'>
<nd ref='4' />
<nd ref='5' />
<nd ref='6' />
<nd ref='7' />
<tag k='maxspeed' v='30' />
<tag k='name' v='fooo' />
</way>
```

Is the only connection between them the same node?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this street needs to be modeled by two (or more) road segments tagged with the same name/class/, different speed and sharing one node each.